# Download html page source code using GWT

Tags: gwt

I am trying to use GWT to download the source code of web pages, but i do not know where to start, can anyone gives me some key word that i can search on google, or gives me some links from tutorials.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, this is typically done with an `XMLHttpRequest`. GWT's analog to `XMLHttpRequest` is [`RequestBuilder`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html), which can be used like so:

```
new RequestBuilder("GET", "http://example.com/page.html").sendRequest("", new RequestCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
    String src = response.getText();
    // do things with the source
  }
  @Override
  public void onError(Request request, Throwable throwable) {
    // handle the error
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Some GWT manual about cross-site scripting
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite

And here some discussion about using RequestBuilder and JSNI
[GWT RequestBuilder - Cross Site Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121374/gwt-requestbuilder-cross-site-requests)

As alternative you can do a page download on the server-side...