# Hitting non-GWT servlet from GWT client-side

Tags: java, web-services, rest, gwt, requestfactory

Let's say there is a 3rd party RESTful web service exposing a GET endpoint at:

```
http://someservice.com/api/askAnyQuestion
```

And I want to hit that service, placing my question on the query string:

```
http://someservice.com/api/askAnyQuestion&q=Does%20my%20dog%20know%20about%20math%3F
```

**How do I hit this service from a client-side GWT application?** I've been reading the `RequestFactory` tutorials, but RF seems to be only for providing a data access layer (DAL) and for CRUDding entities, and I'm not entirely sure if it's appropriate for this use case.

Extra super bonus points if anyone can provide a code sample, and not just a link to the GWT tutorials, which I have already read, or some Googler's blog, which I have also probably read ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem few days ago and tried to implement it with requestBuilder. You will receive a Cross-Domain Scripting issue.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Server#How_can_I_dynamically_fetch_JSON_feeds_from_other_web_domains?

I did handle this by a RPC Request to my Server, and from there a Server-Side HTTP Request to the Cross-Domain URL.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite

```
public static void SendRequest(String method, String notifications) {
    String url = SERVICE_BASE_URL + method;

    JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray notificationsArray =null;
    JSONObject mainRequest = new JSONObject();
    try {
        notificationsArray = new JSONArray(notifications);
        requestObject.put("notifications", notificationsArray);

        mainRequest.put("request", requestObject);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        URL server = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) server.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.writeBytes(mainRequest.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        parseResponse(connection);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html). Successfully used it to work with REST.

```
         RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
         try {
            builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                    // process error
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                    if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                        // process success
                    } else {
                        // process other HTTP response codes
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (RequestException e) {
            // process exception
        }
```

Please also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121374/gwt-requestbuilder-cross-site-requests) for cross site requests related info.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to make a cross-site request. isnt'it?

Comment: You are right. In question, which I mentioned, there is a trick with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. If it doesn't feet the requirements, then yes - we can use some proxy code on the server within the same domain. In my real world scenario REST service is deployed on the same domain.