# Restlet GWT Client and Requests Cross Domain

Tags: rest, gwt, restlet, restlet-2.0

Is it possible perform cross domain requests in the GWT version of Restlet Client?

I need to consume Rest resources (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) from an external API with JSON Data.

I know about Same Origin Policy (SOP) of GWT, but maybe a workaround exists for this restriction...

Restlet documentation with GWT examples is no longer available. This links for example:

http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/46-restlet/112-restlet.html

http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/275-restlet/144-restlet/189-restlet.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call services on another domain ,using the standard GWT [**RequestBuilder**](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html).

Refer for example :[GWT RequestBuilder - Cross Site Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121374/gwt-requestbuilder-cross-site-requests).

Still you want to use [**RestyGwt**](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/). here is the [**Example**](http://blog.javaforge.net/post/30469901979/gwt-rest)

And have a look on [**JsonpRequestBuilder**](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html)

Comment: Problem with RequestBuilder is that is embarrassing make all json parsers manually with native methods (JS Overlay Types).
I looking for a simple framework like Restlet because in server side we already use Restlet.

With RestyGwt I have no lucky with cross domain requests.

Comment: @user2299380 have a look on JsonpRequestBuilder.

Comment: It's the same that RequestBuilder. I must implement model objects with JS overlay types, manually.

Comment: You dont have to map json overlay types to java manually, using GWT autobeans, or gquery databinding is pretty easy.

Comment: I don't know GWT Autobeans, I will take a look. Thanks @Manolo.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `Restlet`, but it seems that it relays in GWT `RequestBuilder`. In consequence, since `RequestBuilder` supports CORS, gwt-restlet should do.

You can use any GWT ajax technique (RPC, RF or RequestBuilder) with CORS without problem. Think that GWT have the same restrictions of any other html/javascript application, and CORS will work if the browser is compatible with CORS (IE9 is not) and the server is correctly configured.

Said that, I encourage you to give a try to [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) which gives you an easy way to deal with ajax. Normally, I use [gwtquery ajax](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax) to consume 3party services because of its syntax and simplicity.

The goal of gQuery syntax is that you can take almost jQuery examples and port them to without so much effort.

This is a simple example:

```java
 ajax(Ajax.createSettings()
   .setUrl("miservice.php")
   .setDataType("json") // txt, json, jsonp, xml
   .setType("get")     // post, get
   .setData($$("param1: 1, param2: 2")) // parameters in json, $$() creates json from string
   .setSuccess(new Function(){ // callback to be run if the request succeeds 
     public void f() {
       // The response when dataType=json is a javascript object (Properties)
       Properties json = getDataProperties();
     }
   })
 );
```

In the case of JSON (or XML) I use [gQuery databinding](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding#JSON) to map the response with java objects.

For instance:

```java
interface Site extends JsonBuilder {
  long getId();
  String getUrl();
  Site setId(long id);
  Site setUrl(String url);
}

...
Site site = GWT.create(Site.class);
site.load(getDataProperties();
Window.alert(site.getUrl();
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I looking for a simple way to consuming Rest resources with Json. Restlet client for GWT seems to be the indicated, however documentation is no longer available in the official web site.

Comment: Yep, I saw that the gwt documentation is not available anymore. I took a look to theirs github repo and there are no examples there. Seems like they dont pay much attention in gwt. Anyway, I just proposed an option which is as simple as `restlet` (IMO simpler though). Good luck.