# GWT with existing REST backend

Tags: java, rest, gwt

I researched a lot about it, but I wasn't able to reach a conclusion about this matter.

I'm creating a new front-end in GWT, using GWT-Platform and GIN, for an existing application. But I can't figure out which is the best way to interact with the existing REST API.

What I found up to now is that I can use RequestBuilder to do the calls, and that also exists  the RestyGWT framework for REST communications. But I don't know how to integrate any of them with GIN Injector. And I have doubts on how to translate the JSON return from the service to the JTO available in the client code translated by GWT.

The last one specially due to a legacy code that translate the Beans from the server to a kind of generic Json format.

So what I want to know is do anybody have experience integrating legacy backend to a new GWT front-end with REST. How they integrate both? How they solve, if experienced, the Beans integration?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ümit, If you are worried about the "communication" between backend and frontend don´t get stress:

Something like:

```
  public String serializeToJson(YoutEntity report) {
    AutoBean<YoutEntity > bean = AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(report);
    return AutoBeanCodex.encode(bean).getPayload();
  }

  public YoutEntity deserializeCompanyFromJson(String json) {
    AutoBean<YoutEntity > bean = 
                AutoBeanCodex.decode(factoryYourEntity, YoutEntity .class, json);
    return bean.as();
  }
```

is perfectly possible using [Autobeans](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#decode%28%29)!

And using GWT you can share your entities between Client and Server, so you don´t need to touch anything.

Also, in our last project using Apache Wink as a REST client, in the server using the correct annotations we were able to have the Entity automatically from the JSON, so is even easier (but I think most of the REST libraries can do the same).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question touches a couple of different aspects both client-side but also server-side.

In general there is nothing special about integration between `GWT` and a `REST API`.
On the GWT side there are different ways to consume a REST API:

- RequestBuilder to manually create the HTTP Requests to the REST API. You have to parse the JSON payload. There are different ways to do this:

  - [Javascript OVerlay Types](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html).
  - 3rd party library ([Piriti](https://github.com/hpehl/piriti))
  - [AutoBeans](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean)
- [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html#JSON_Encoder_Decoders) (backend + GWT. See this [tutorial](http://css.dzone.com/tips/spring-rest-services-gwt))
- Restlet has a [GWT client](http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/editions/gwt/examples) (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106294/restlet-gwt-client-and-requests-cross-domain) for more details).

`GIN` per se doesn't have anything to do with the communication with a REST API. 
It's only responsible for dependency injection on the client side.

The translation of beans to JSON depends on the backend. `Spring` can basically automatically serialize Java beans into JSON using `Jackson`.