# GWT Request builder, send data from one port to another port

Tags: gwt

I hava a GWT project running on port 3000, and i have a Java project running on port8080. Now i just want to send a string from port 3000 to 8080. Would it be possible by using GWT request builder? or how to make this process happen by using other technology? 
I also need data to be sent from port 8080 to port 3000....

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

I'm assuming your java project should be a service/webapp, since you have mentioned the port in which your java project is running is 8080(default tomcat port).

Your access from GWT project running on port 3000 to java project running on port 8080 is a Cross Site Request.

References on Cross site request:

- http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html
  (Please read section : Access Restrictions: Same Origin Policy)
- [GWT RequestBuilder - Cross Site Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121374/gwt-requestbuilder-cross-site-requests)